# Accessing an android application from a website?

Tags: android, google-maps, latitude-longitude, android-maps

I want to develop an application that can read user's latitude and longitude. I can do this by `LocationManager` I can do this. But if where as i want to pass this latitude and longitude data when even the user request from an external website.

This means i want to connect the app through a website and retrieve the latitude and logitude data then pass it to that particular website.

Is this possible in Android ?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do, is have an App with [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) integrated. Your web App can fire a request off to [Google servers](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#send-msg) to tell a / all user(s) to send their GPS details directly to your server.

Answer (score 0):

So you want create website that gets data from android app, did i get it right?

You need add javascript to your website for example:

```
"<div class=\"location\"> <input type=\"button\" value=\"get location\" onClick=\"getAndroidLocation()\" />"
                    + "<script language=\"javascript\"> function getAndroidLocation() { AndroidFunction.getAndroidLocation(); } </script>";
```

And for your app you need add javascript interface. Example:

```
mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "AndroidFunction");

    public void getAndroidLocation(){
          //Do your staff and send location 

    }
```

Comment: Yes correct ! Lets assume i've an user on his personal computer. He installs my app that can send data to the database when ever user clicks on the button in desktop view.